# Registering users with Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, registration

The following is my form template, which is loaded in the header of my register.html page and displays in a div #register-tpl. It displays fine. The user is prompted to register with a username, an email, and a password:

```
<script id="register-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <form class="form-register" role="form">
        <h1>Sign up!</h1>
        <h2><span class="typcn typcn-user-add"></span>&nbsp;Create an account</h2>
        <p><input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus=""></p>
        <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required=""></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus=""></p>
        <p><button class="button" type="submit">Sign up</button></p>
        <p>Already have an account? <a class="app-link" href="admin.html">Log in!</a></p>
    </form>
</script>
```

The following is my Javascript code for adding a new user to the database:

```
                var RegisterView = Parse.View.extend({
                template: Handlebars.compile($('#register-tpl').html()),
                events: {
                    'submit .form-register': 'register'
                },
                register: function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;     
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    var email = document.getElementById('input').value;

                    var user = new Parse.User();
                    user.set("username", username);
                    user.set("password", password);
                    user.set("email", email);

                    user.signUp(username, password, email, {

                        success: function(user) {
                            var welcomeView = new WelcomeView({ model: user });
                            welcomeView.render();
                            $('.register-container').html(welcomeView.el);
                        },

                        error: function(user, error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                },
                render: function(){
                    this.$el.html(this.template());
                }
            });
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not submitting the required information? It's not even recognizing the creation of a new user on my Parse dashboard. Is there something fundamentally flawed here? Thanks, and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved specifying a form to be submitted in the success callback: document.getElementById("user-add").submit(). I also had a common spelling mistake when setting the field variables. It should have read var username = form.username.value; instead of username = document.username.value;!

```
            var RegisterView = Parse.View.extend({
                template: Handlebars.compile($('#register-tpl').html()),
                events: {
                    'submit .user-add': 'register'
                },
                register: function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    user = new Parse.User();

                    var form = document.getElementById("user-add");

                    var username = form.username.value;
                    var password = form.password.value;
                    var email = form.email.value;

                    user.set("username", username);
                    user.set("password", password);
                    user.set("email", email);

                    user.signUp(null, {
                        success: function(user) {
                            form.submit();
                            window.location.href = 'admin.html';
                        },
                        error: function(user, error) {
                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                },
                render: function(){
                    this.$el.html(this.template());
                }
            });
```